# Android thread test does not work

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hi I'm beginner with android development and I have a problem with my following test code:

Main Activity:

```
package com.test.thread;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txt    = null;
Button btStart  = null;
Button btStop   = null;

TestClass test = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt     = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView); 
    btStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_start);
    btStop  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_stop);

    test    =  new TestClass(this, txt);

    btStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            test.Stop();
        }
    });
    btStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread t = new Thread(){                    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(50);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    while(test.isStop()){
                                        try {
                                            wait(1000);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        test.DoSomeThing();                                     
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }               
                    }catch( InterruptedException  e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

TestCLas.java:

```
package com.tutorial.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestClass{

private boolean stopIter    = false;
private TextView txtV       = null;
private int count           = 0;
private Context ctx         = null;

public TestClass(Context ct, TextView tv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    txtV        =   tv;
    stopIter    =   false;
    count       =   0; 
    ctx         =   ct;
}
public boolean isStop() { return stopIter; }
public void Stop()
{
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "stop the test" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    count = 0;
    txtV.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    stopIter =  true;
}
public void DoSomeThing(){
    txtV.setText(Integer.toString(count));
}

}
```

I want to manage my `activity`'s viewer with threads. I launch a thread in order to modify `TextView`'s text (each sec) when the `start` button is clicked and stop it when `stop` button is clicked. But it does not work, it crashes without any exception. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I've never seen a crash without exception, can you post the logcat when it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait(1000);
```

This should NEVER be done on the UI thread.

The UI thread is the one that update the GUI, and communicates with Android to say everything is working as expected. When you have a thread delay on the UI thread, the message to and from the android system get held back, and you app appears to the system as if it has crashed.